# Is it possible to prevent, or at least detect, SSH session re-use?

Tags: ssh

I have been taking advantage of session reuse to speed up my connections to various production servers by setting up my ~/.ssh/config file like so:

```
Host server.company.org
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%r@%h-%p
ControlPersist 600
```

This is great, but if my first ssh session is opened without agent forwarding, e.g. `ssh server.company.org`, and I later start another ssh command that requires agent forwarding, e.g. `ssh -A server.company.org`, the agent forwarding does not work.

Is it possible to force the second ssh session **not** to use the existing socket, other than by deleting the contents of `~/.ssh/sockets` first?  If not, is there a reliable way to detect that an existing socket is about to be reused?  I'm encountering this problem in scripts, so bombing out with a suitable error message would be acceptable behaviour.

Comment: If you would describe the problem you are trying to solve using agent forwarding in the first place, then we may be able to provide you with a better solution that does not involve agent forwarding.

Comment: I'm doing various tasks on servers that can only be accessed via a bastion host, and that require ssh keys to access. The ssh keys are not stored on the host I start off on, but are held in a password manager.

Comment: A more secure way to use a bastion host is with `ssh -o ProxyCommand='ssh -W %h:%p bastion' target`. No agent forwarding required.

Comment: I actually do use that method a lot (also via the config file), although not all my scripts are set up to expect it - I don't want the scripts to have the bastion address hardcoded in, so using this would require all users to have their config file setup to do this.

Comment: That said, I take your point about security, and that is probably the way I'll go.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can force the `ControlMaster auto` to be overridden like so:

```
ssh -A -S none server.company.org
```

...where `-S none` means do not use a Control Master.

You can also check whether a `ControlMaster` is running for a particular host:

```
ssh -O check server.company.org
```

...and kill it similarly:

```
ssh -O exit server.company.org
```

Comment: While this is technically the answer I was looking for, as discussed with @kasperd above it is probably not the ideal way to solve the problem.